# How can I override styles in tabulator?

Tags: css, vue.js, tabulator

I'm using Vue Tabulator here to over ride the column header not to use ellipsis when I continue to reduce the size of the column. Can't we update the column header in tabulator using inline style?

`<VueTabulator  ref="tabulator" v-model="receipts" :options="options" style="white-space: normal; text-overflow: clip"/>`

But when I inspected the element, the values of white-space and text-overflow didn't change

[image]

I also tried inside the style tag within my vue component. No luck

```css
<style>
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-col-content .tabulator-col-title{
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
</style>
```

Comment: 3 possible cases: you need an `important` or your CSS selector is not the good one (maybe the classes should be collapsed rather than separated with a space?) or you need `deep` to select it properly.

Comment: Stunning bro. Adding !important did the trick. Do you mind sharing how did that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `!important` fixed the issue.

This comes from CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

That one is easier to understand too: https://specifishity.com/

The thing is that you do have some classes coming from the package you're using.
And there is probably a higher specificity there, hence why your default CSS doesn't work.
`!important` is quite overkill and not recommend usually because it defeats the whole purpose of CSS cascade by nuking it.

Meanwhile, for 3rd party packages you don't really have control overall: it's totally fine and quite regular to force an overwrite like that. Common practice for Bootstrap, Vuetify etc...and smaller packages.